# Flutter Xcode Build Failed - 'TARGET_OS_WATCHOS' is not defined, evaluates to 0

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

I have created Flutter Project. It's working on Windows OS for Android Successfully. I have tried for the first time to run it in XCode (Mac OS) but getting some error as follows.

> Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                           14.3s
> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> In file included from
> /xxx/xxx/xxx/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Utilities/FIRAuthURLPresenter.m:24:
> /xxx/xxx/xxx/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Utilities/FIRAuthDefaultUIDelegate.
> h:18:24: error: 'TARGET_OS_WATCHOS' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
> #if !TARGET_OS_OSX && !TARGET_OS_WATCHOS
> ^
> 1 error generated.
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Analyzing workspace
> note: Constructing build description
> note: Build preparation complete
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

I have added error only for reference. If you need anything please do let me know.

Comment: When `clang` is compiling, the `-target ${ARCH}-apple-watchos6.2` command-line arg with `-mwatchos-version-min=6.2` arg causes right macros to be defined (and simulator-build passes `-mwatchsimulator-version-min=6.2` arg instead of second one)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xcode 12.5, this issue could be solved by changing **TARGET_OS_WATCHOS** to **TARGET_OS_WATCH**

You could also refer to this GitHub issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5034

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of your files have illegal characters or syntax errors.

remove extra line like

```
#endif without if
```

it will work.